# Método insert não salva os dados

Tags: android, banco-de-dados, sqlite, sql-insert

Tenho um aplicativo em que o objetivo (no momento) é pegar os dados digitados em um formulário e salvar no Banco de Dados. E o método insert da minha DataSource sempre me retorna false não entendo o porque. O processo de salvar pela Controller retorna certo, mas na hora de checar o insert, ele retorna false, como na imagem abaixo. Tudo me retorna true até chegar nessa parte. Estou a mais de uma semana tentando entender porque não funciona, já fiz, refiz o aplicativo, revi códigos-fonte pra checar se estava tudo ok, nada me parece fora do normal (id retorna 0 sempre, os dados retornam certos mas não salva). Vou até mandar como está os meus gets e sets e a DataModel.

Gets e sets:

```
public class Formulario {

    private int id;
    private String titulo;
    private String data;
    private String info;
    private double valor;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitulo() {
        return titulo;
    }

    public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
        this.titulo = titulo;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getInfo() {
        return info;
    }

    public void setInfo(String info) {
        this.info = info;
    }

    public double getValor() {
        return valor;
    }

    public void setValor(double valor) {
        this.valor = valor;
    }
}
```

DataModel:

```
public class FormularioDataModel {

    private final static String TABELA = "financas";

    private final static String id = "id";
    private final static String titulo = "titulo";
    private final static String valor = "valor";
    private final static String data = "data";
    private final static String info = "info";

    private static String queryCriarTabela = "";

    public static String criarTabela() {

        queryCriarTabela = "CREATE TABLE " + TABELA;
        queryCriarTabela += "(";
        queryCriarTabela += id + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, ";
        queryCriarTabela += titulo + " TEXT, ";
        queryCriarTabela += valor + " REAL, ";
        queryCriarTabela += data + " TEXT, ";
        queryCriarTabela += info + " TEXT, ";
        queryCriarTabela += ")";

        return queryCriarTabela;
    }

    public static String getTABELA() {
        return TABELA;
    }

    public static String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public static String getTitulo() {
        return titulo;
    }

    public static String getValor() {
        return valor;
    }

    public static String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public static String getInfo() {
        return info;
    }

    public static String getQueryCriarTabela() {
        return queryCriarTabela;
    }

    public static void setQueryCriarTabela(String queryCriarTabela) {
        FormularioDataModel.queryCriarTabela = queryCriarTabela;
    }
}
```

DataSource:

public class DataSource extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
private static final String DB_NAME = "financas.sqlite";
private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

SQLiteDatabase db;
Cursor cursor;

public DataSource(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);

    db = getWritableDatabase();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    try{

        db.execSQL(FormularioDataModel.criarTabela());

    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("Media", "Log ---> ERRO "+e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {


}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que é mostrado na linha do erro? Data tag "DS".

Comment: 2019-03-29 22:30:55.046 28076-28076/com.dz.finanas E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting titulo=Conta info=Pagar logo valor=250.0 data=29/03/2019
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: financas (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO financas(titulo,info,valor,data) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        
2019-03-29 22:33:19.388 845-1018/? E/WifiStateMachine: mIsFullScanOngoing: false, mSendScanResultsBroadcast: false    


Tirei as linhas pra caber o Logcat

Comment: Mas e o SQLiteOpenHelper? Você criou a tabela por lá?

Comment: Ou foi apenas por essa classe?

Comment: Sim, extendi o SQLiteOpenHelper na DataSource, aí coloquei o construtor, o onCreate e o onUpgrade. Coloquei o método insert lá e o método salvar na Controller. A controller retorna tudo true, quando chega na hora de checar o insert, é aí que retorna false, como ta na img.

Comment: Então.. o erro diz que essa tabela não existe! É isso! `no such table: financas` melhor você inserir mais códigos!

Comment: É isso que não entendo. Eu postei os gets e sets e a DataModel, a tabela tem que existir ué

Comment: Não necessariamente... Coloque o  `SQLiteOpenHelper ` também.

Comment: Atualizei na pergunta já

Comment: Deu certo David?

Comment: Resolvi. O problema não era o projeto, e sim o APK que foi instalado. Reinstalei o APK e resolveu. Mas obrigado pela a ajuda :)

Comment: A linha que eu coloquei na resposta estava errada também! A última vírgula gera erro!

Comment: Dá uma olhada > https://sqliteonline.com/#fiddle-5ca7c4d71f1ba54xju4kfo1t

Comment: Minha resposta aparentemente está correta, pois além de tudo, eu disse para você re-instalar o aplicativo.

Answer (score 1):

O erro que eu reparei está na criação da tabela. A string concatenada (`queryCriarTabela`) do método `criarTabela()` retorna esse valor:

```
    CREATE TABLE financas (
      id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
      titulo TEXT,
      valor REAL,
      data TEXT,
      info TEXT, // <-- erro
    ); // <-- coloque o ponto e vírgula no final por segurança
```

Esta vírgula no final não deixa a tabela ser criada.

**LEMBRE-SE**

Sempre que você fizer uma alteração em alguma tabela do banco usando o `helper`, você precisa realizar uma das ações abaixo:

- Criar um `drop table if exists` da tabela antiga
- Ou desinstalar e instalar novamente o aplicativo

Eu não encontrei outros motivos para falha na criação da tabela. Mas podem haver.

Inclusive, o seu `DataSource` no método `onCreate` deve ter capturado essa exceção nesta linha:

```
Log.e("Media", "Log ---> ERRO "+e.getMessage());
```